# Nauty software package and weighted graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I am working with software package Nauty. It there a way to add weighted graphs in nauty software package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Weighted (coloured) vertices are supported, weighted edges are not.  There is an example in the manual showing how to make an equivalent unweighted graph. In the future both nauty and traces will handle weighted graph directly.

Comment: Thank you! It would be great to have the ability to work with weighted graphs in Nauty as it seems to be a really useful tool for graph isomorphism problems!

Answer (score 4):

Nauty does not have such an option, but there are various techniques known that allow you to reduce the weighted case to the non-weighted one. See e.g. Sect 3.4 of our paper [Computing symmetry groups of polyhedra](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/S1461157014000400).

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look! However at this point is important for me to find a way to represent the coefficients of a problem with weight/lengths/colours!

Comment: Well, how you represent weights is an entirely different question. In the setting of computing automorphisms and isomorphisms all what matters is that different weights are represented by different integer numbers (or colours).

Comment: I agree with you and of course colours is a good way to represent the weight in my graphs. I am trying to find the command in dreadnaut for adding this colours on my graph and doesn't seem to be clearly written anywhere!

Comment: There is no such command in dreadnaut. You will have to supply it the already prepared non-weighted graph.